# How can I tap to close AVPlayer in Swift 5?

Tags: swift

**I'm creating an extremely simple game, and I've hidden the video controls.**

```
@IBAction func playVideo1(_ sender: Any) {

    // play video connected to button 1
    guard let firstVideo = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Video1", ofType:"mp4") else {
            debugPrint("Video not found")
                return
            }

    // create an AVPlayer, passing it mp4
    let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: firstVideo))


    // Create a new AVPlayerViewController and pass it a reference to the player.
    let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
    controller.player = player

    controller.showsPlaybackControls = false



    // Modally present the player and call the player's play() method when complete.
    present(controller, animated: true) {
        player.play()
    } 
} // end playVideo1
```

One of the two options would be OK.

**Option 1:** Tap to close the video.

**Option 2:** Have the AVPlayer close automatically at the end of the video.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Your code never showed or “opened” the player so there is nothing to “close”. All you did so far is create it. Show the rest of the code. How do you “open” it?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40099223/close-avplayer-when-movie-is-complete

Comment: Still new to Swift and App development. I updated my question to include all of my code.

Comment: tap where ?? , you need when tap on video close it?

Comment: Tap on the Apple logo on the back of the iPad. Remove case where applicable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a tap gesture recognizer to AVPlayerViewController's view (for closing on tap), or you could subscribe to AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime notification (for closing when video ends playing). Something like this:

```
@IBAction func playVideo1(_ sender: Any) {

    // play video connected to button 1
    guard let firstVideo = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Video1", ofType:"mp4") else {
            debugPrint("Video not found")
                return
            }

    // create an AVPlayer, passing it mp4
    let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: firstVideo))


    // Create a new AVPlayerViewController and pass it a reference to the player.
    let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
    controller.player = player

    controller.showsPlaybackControls = false

    //for closing when video ends
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(closePlayer), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: controller.player?.currentItem)

    //for closing on tap
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(closePlayer))
    controller.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

    // Modally present the player and call the player's play() method when complete.
    present(controller, animated: true) {
        player.play()
    }
} // end playVideo1

@objc func closePlayer() {
    dismiss(animated: true)
    //if you go notification route, don't forget to remove observer
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

Comment: Impressive! Haven’t tested this yet but your code is clear and readable, even for a noob like me. Will come back after I test. Thank you!

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you, Predrag.

Answer (score 2):

For closing the videoPlayer when on user tap you can use the following-

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(closePlayerOnTouch))
    controller.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
```

and then add this after the button -

```
@objc func closePlayerOnTouch() {
    dismiss(animated: true)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

@Predrag's answer is really awesome though.

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var btnPlay: UIButton!

var player:AVPlayer?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func btnPress(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (btnPlay.titleLabel?.text == "Play") {
        initPlayer()
        btnPlay.setTitle("Stop", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    } else {
        stopPlayer()
        btnPlay.setTitle("Play", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
}

func initPlayer()  {
    if let play = player {
        print("playing")
        play.play()
    } else {
        print("player allocated")
        player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: "http://streaming.radio.rtl.fr/rtl-1-48-192")!)
        print("playing")
        player!.play()
    }
}

func stopPlayer() {
    if let play = player {
        print("stopped")
        play.pause()
        player = nil
        print("player deallocated")
    } else {
        print("player was already deallocated")
    }
}
}
```

Comment: try to execute the stopPlayer()